# Copy only latest files in Command Prompt

Tags: file, command, prompt

I have two directories with the same files. On the source directory, I always make updates. Now I just want to copy the updated files from the source directory to the destination directory. So it would be like updating files instead of copying all files.

I had also tried on the "Batch script to copy newest file". Though it worked well but it only copies the newest files.

Is there something that could compare the dates of the files from the directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [RoboCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx), it has switches for filtering files based on dates

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the files or images from one network to another network  then you can use the command  **robocopy**.